# Can I Select This <li> With Out Adding Any Classes with CSS selector?

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="accordion2">
<ul>
    <li>
        <h3>Lorem</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
            **<li><a href="#">SELECT THIS <li> WITH CSS WITHOUT ADDING CLASS TO IT</a>**
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Hi, i want to add background image to my li that has lower level li, question is can i select it with css selector? I dont want to use classes but if theres not another solution i  have to. Thanks

Comment: Don't do this in real life: `#accordion2 > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(2)`

Comment: @MelanciaUK note that http://pivotallabs.com/css-first-child-nth-child-and-last-child-are-not-like-eq/

Comment: Your markup is incorrect. You're closing tags out of order.

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov I think it should be `#accordion2 > ul > li > ul:nth-child(2)` you are specifying it to select the second child of the li instead of the actual li

Comment: @Aboca Nope, http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov oh yes, you are right i'm in the clouds today

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
#accordion2 > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(2) {
   background: ...
}
```

The index of the first child item is 1.

If you need to support IE, the first version that supports this is IE9

Comment: Also, you might want to cancel out the children with `#accordion2 > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(2) ul` if they shouldn't inherit that parents properties. Like [this example](http://jsbin.com/veruru/1/edit)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `background-image` property:

```
#accordion2 > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(2){
    background-image: url('http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120506145055/disneyjessieseries/images/1/1d/20px-Facebook-icon.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    list-style-type: none;    
    text-indent: 20px;    
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/t56utzs2/3/)

Take a look here [background-image Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)

Comment: Doesn't match what OP wants

Comment: Sorry my bad. Update my answer.

Comment: Didn't see he specify the `li` element he wants to style.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this

```
div#accordion2 ul li ul li:nth-child(2){
    *style here*
}
```

Comment: better to start from first-child rather and avoid nth-child for IE

Answer (score 1):

```
#accordion2 ul li ul li {
   background-color: grey;
}
```

I don't like nesting so deep, it will confuse you and scare you away xD!
In this case, create a class that has a property with a different background color or image and add that class to the specific elements you want to mark.

CSS:

```
.red-li {
   background-color: red;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li class="red-li">Im Red</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That would match both the intended li and the other above.

Comment: Indeed, my answer isn't good. That is why my suggestion is better. By going deeper in levels manually, it will eventually clash with other elements on the same level. Either id or classes are better solution than handpicking them like that.